# I don't see a way to generate the APIKey under my softlayer account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to follow the doc here: https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/generate-api-key

- Access the Users screen in the Customer Portal. Refer to Access the Users Screen.
- Click the Generate link in the API Key column for the desired user to generate the API key.

However, I don't see the API Key column.  Does my account need be in certain role in order to have the option to generate API Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this permission enabled to see or generate api key (To see APIKEY column):

> - Add New User

Probably you don't have this enabled, please ask for it to your parent user or master user

Just in case, if your user has an apiKey generated, you can see this in the below link:

- https://control.softlayer.com/account/user/profile

See: **API Access Information** section